# Breaking up a string scanned from a boardingpass

Tags: php

This is a string i got from scanning my boarding pass.

```
M1BEAVER/ALEXANDERMR EMGWEQE LHRCPHBA 0816 142M019D0014 13B>30B1WM8141BBA 29 BA 15700353 8
```

I tried looking for different solutions and I have been seeing some python and java boarding pass parsers which is none of the languages i am specifically skilled in. So **php** is the way to go.

**This is to be used in a web application with a mysql database where the data will be stored**

---

How would I break it up into different individual values specifically the ones highlighted with **bold**. It has to be done automatically with different string lengths like the name. So for example:

> M1**BEAVER/ALEXANDERMR** EMGWEQE LHRCPH**BA 0816** 142M019D0014 13B>30B1WM8141BBA 29 BA 15700353 8

Will be an output of:

> BEAVER/ALEXANDERMR: My name
>
> EMGWEQE: My booking reference number
>
> LHRCPHBA: Flying from LHR to CPH on a BA flight.
>
> 0816: Flight number

The rest of the string is useless in my case but it is the information you get from a scan.

I know how I could divide this into the different values I want but with a different change in names, flight numbers and airport codes I just don't have a clue how to dynamically adjust and separate to the different values I want.

Thank you all in advanced.

Comment: Show what have you tried so far

Comment: Are the spaces in the string consistent across scans?

Comment: Welcome to SO, Please consider the following [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: You have to make this question more specific. Even though I think the question is very interesting, two things make your question bad: 1) You did not try to write any PHP code yourself - you even tagged it PHP and jQuery, which language do you desire? 2) You questions does not describe the problem completely (e.g. how to identify the flight number and is the number of chars before BA 0816 always the same). Edit the question and make it more clear.

Comment: is there always 2 char before lastname?

Comment: Hi. Okay so i hope i elaborated a little bit more on my question, i have not tried specifically coding an example for this as the string lengths would change with different names and flight numbers. And yes there is always to chars before last name.

Comment: No. That's not enough. I personally don't have a clue about boarding pass scans specifications. Nobody can guide you through this if you don't add more information. Are the strings always in the same order or do you need to identify/search for them? Are they all always present? What info do you need to extract? Etc. etc. Most likely you'll end up doing something with a regular expression.

Comment: Added an answer, would that code be a good solution? of course the echo wouldn't be there in practice it will be put into a database.

Answer (score 0):

Would this be a solution? I did some digging. Since the scans are consistent with all boarding passes so all spaces match.

```
$data = "M1BEAVER/ALEXANDERMR EMGWEQE LHRCPHBA 0816 142M019D0014 13B>30B1WM8141BBA 29 BA 15700353 8";

list($name, $bookinreference, $flight, $fnumber) = preg_split('/\s+/', $data);

echo substr($name, 2) . ' ' . substr($flight, 0, 3) . ' ' . substr($flight, 3, 3) . ' ' . substr($flight, 6) . $fnumber . ' ';
```

Output:

```
BEAVER/ALEXANDERMR LHR CPH BA0816
```

Using substr() to remove unwanted characters and splitting LHRCPHBA into LHR CPH BA.

Answer (score -1):

What you are looking for is explode():

```
$string = "M1BEAVER/ALEXANDERMR EMGWEQE LHRCPHBA 0816 142M019D0014 13B>30B1WM8141BBA 29 BA 15700353 8";
$array = explode(" ", $string);
var_dump($array);
```

Output:

```
array(10) {
  [0]=>
  string(20) "M1BEAVER/ALEXANDERMR"
  [1]=>
  string(7) "EMGWEQE"
  [2]=>
  string(8) "LHRCPHBA"
  [3]=>
  string(4) "0816"
  [4]=>
  string(12) "142M019D0014"
  [5]=>
  string(17) "13B>30B1WM8141BBA"
  [6]=>
  string(2) "29"
  [7]=>
  string(2) "BA"
  [8]=>
  string(8) "15700353"
  [9]=>
  string(1) "8"
}
```

Try it here: 
[PHP Sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/1fb47b10a8042d3949da21bbfcf90b33564a24b2)

Edit: This answer is only valid if the spaces are consistent.

Comment: Oh yes this is something of what I could use, great answer. The spaces are consistent on all boarding passes. I did some digging and figured something out too that is working as well i will add my own solution.